# How to solve the lack of symmetry in this line rasterization algorithm?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I am working on an algorithm to snap 3D lines to a 3D tessellated space.

Here is a 2D example of the algorithm that works for positive and negative slopes between -1 and 1 inclusive.

Using the slope to calculate the value of y at each x results in slow and error-prone floating calculations. The solution is to simulate the division with a remainder variable.

When `dx >= dy`, start with an initial remainder variable `ry = 0`. Then, for each `x` increment, add `dy` to `ry` variable. When it surpasses `dx`, increment y, then set `ry` equal to `ry - dx`.

```
function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let points = []
  let dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
  let dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
  // The remainder variable for y axes. 
  // No rx is created because we are assuming dx >= dy.
  let ry = 0;
  // Current value of y for a given point
  let y = 0;

  // The slope could be positive or negative, so increments coordinates as they go down or up.
  let pointIncrement;
  if (x2 > x1) {
    pointIncrement = 1;
  } else if (x2 < x1) {
    pointIncrement = -1;
    y = y1
  }
  for (let x = x1; pointIncrement < 0 ? x >= x2 : x <= x2; x += pointIncrement) {
    if (ry >= dx) {
      ry -= dx;
      y += pointIncrement;
    }
    // Add dy to ry until it surpasses dx. This simulates the division of dy/dx for slope.
    ry += dy;
    points.push([x, y])
  }
  return points
}
```

Now, if you call the function with a slope of 1/4th:

```
line(0,0,20,5)
```

You get the following results:

```
[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1],[8,2],[9,2],[10,2],[11,2],[12,3],[13,3],[14,3],[15,3],[16,4],[17,4],[18,4],[19,4],[20,5]]
```

Now, if you call it again but in the negative direction, then reverse the coordinate order:

```
line(20,5,0,0).reverse()
```

You get the following results:

```
[[0,0],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,2],[6,2],[7,2],[8,2],[9,3],[10,3],[11,3],[12,3],[13,4],[14,4],[15,4],[16,4],[17,5],[18,5],[19,5],[20,5]]
```

Why is this occurring?

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem to make the negative slope symmetric to the positive slope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upward direction, you are calculating `y = y1 + floor((x-x1) * dy / dx)`.  In the downward direction, you are calculating `y = y1 + ceil((x-x1) * dy / dx)`

In both cases, this produces "unbalanced" lines, with `dy/dx` points with `y ==  y1`, but only one point with `y == y2`.

What you want to calculate is `y = y1 + round((x-x1) * dy / dx)`.  That will make the line ends balanced.  If you want the upward and downward directions to be exactly symmetric, then you need to take care to make sure that 0.5 rounds in the same direction in both cases.

One way to accomplish rounding in this kind of implementation is with an offset.  If A and B are integers, and B is positive, then `round(A/B) == floor((A+floor(B/2))/B)`.  This `floor(B/2)` offset can be added to your remainder at the start.

Taking care to make sure 0.5 always rounds up, you can fix your asymmetry just by changing the initial value for `ry` to:

```
  let ry = y2 >= y1 ? Math.floor(dx/2) : Math.floor((dx-1)/2);
```

There are a couple other bugs in your code, too, though.  If I fix them all, it looks like this:

```
function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let points = []
  // increment direction for x axis
  const incX = x2 >= x1 ? 1 : -1;
  // increment direction for y axis
  const incY = y2 >= y1 ? 1 : -1;
  // absolute span in x and y
  const dx = (x2 - x1) * incX;
  const dy = (y2 - y1) * incY;

  // The remainder variable for y axes. 
  let ry = y2 >= y1 ? Math.floor(dx/2) : Math.floor((dx-1)/2);
  // Current value of y for a given point
  let y = y1;
  
  for (let x = x1; incX < 0 ? x >= x2 : x <= x2; x += incX) {
    if (ry >= dx) {
      ry -= dx;
      y += incY;
    }
    // Add dy to ry until it surpasses dx. This simulates the division of dy/dx for slope.
    ry += dy;
    points.push([x, y])
  }
  return points
}
```